# Background color overlap issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having a simple (but frustrating) issue with my background. I currently have it as a static background image and a solid color for my content space. For some reason the content color is not showing up? I feel like i've gone through everything to fix it but no dice. Any suggestions?

```
body {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  background-image:url(../img/bglogo.jpg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
#contentcontainer { 
  max-width: 960px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  float: none; 
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left:10px;
  background-color: #fffdf8;
}
```

The website in question can be found here: http://mikesbaum.com/plan9alehouse/index.html

Comment: Also validator.w3.org shows 17 separate errors and 7 warnings for your HTML, including duplicated sections and unclosed elements, which can cause havoc with your CSS, so you might want to get those taken care of, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Floats to position your divs side by side.  As such, the parent div does not have access to the height of those divs as they populate.  This leaves the parent div at 0px height,  making it invisible on the page.

Add 'overflow:auto;' to your #contentcontainer class and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the contents of `#contentcontainer` (home, about, etc.) are all floated, and you're not clearing it. When you do this, the parent element doesn't wrap the child element. If you look at the height of `#contentcontainer` you will see that it is set to 0.

To fix this, you need to clear the floated sections. the quickest way to do this is to just add an empty div as the last child in `#contentcontainer` with the css `clear: both;`:

```
<section id='contentcontainer'>
 <section id='home'>...</section>
 ...
 ...
 <div style='clear: both;'></div>
</section>
```

Usually if you find yourself clearing floats a lot, most people will create a clear or clearfix class, and just use the class name for the div instead of using inline css.